# Kubernetes ( and then rancher) timeout

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, rancher, k3s

I have set up a rancher 2.4 little infrastructure using k3s 1.18.4 and MariaDB as backend.

Everything ran ok for 25 days, but now, I can't log on rancher anymore, it's like the API is not responding anymore on 443, and container are now crashing since then can't contact kubernetes cluster.

I have an Nginx load balancer on another server, that works fine for days also but now everything timeout :

==> https_lb.log <==

```sh
yyyy.yyy.yyy.yyy [18/Aug/2020:07:09:42 +0200] TCP 502 0 0 31.510 "xx.xx.xx.xx:443" "0" "0" "31.508"
```

==> error.log <==

```sh
2020/08/18 07:10:02 [error] 29966#29966: *81 connect() failed (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: yyyy.yyy.yyy.yyy, server: 0.0.0.0:443, upstream: "xx.xx.xx.xx:443", bytes from/to client:0/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/0
```

The API answer well on the 6443 port for example:

```sh
curl https://localhost:6443/ping --insecure
pong
```

The service seems up as well:

```sh
kubectl get services
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.43.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   7h53m

kubectl get nodes
NAME    STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
k3sh1   Ready    master   32d   v1.18.4+k3s1
k3sw4   Ready    <none>   28d   v1.18.6+k3s1
k3sw3   Ready    <none>   28d   v1.18.6+k3s1
k3sw2   Ready    <none>   28d   v1.18.6+k3s1
```

And of course, everythink is now KO, since there's timeout everywhere, for example:

```sh
2020-08-17T22:40:04.421339807+02:00 stderr F ERROR: logging before flag.Parse: E0817 20:40:04.418868       1 reflector.go:251] github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/lib/controller/controller.go:603: Failed to watch *v1.PersistentVolumeClaim: Get https://10.43.0.1:443/api/v1/persistentvolumeclaims?resourceVersion=15748753&timeoutSeconds=499&watch=true: dial tcp 10.43.0.1:443: connect: connection refused
2020-08-17T22:40:04.421345285+02:00 stderr F ERROR: logging before flag.Parse: E0817 20:40:04.418809       1 reflector.go:251] github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/lib/controller/controller.go:609: Failed to watch *v1.StorageClass: Get https://10.43.0.1:443/apis/storage.k8s.io/v1/storageclasses?resourceVersion=15748753&timeoutSeconds=381&watch=true: dial tcp 10.43.0.1:443: connect: connection refused
```

And so on...

Can someone help me to look at the good direction to fix this, please?

**Update 1** :

Liste of pods running

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -owide
NAMESPACE       NAME                                       READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE    IP               NODE    NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
recette         app-test-65c94f999c-g6t56                  1/1     Running            0          15d    10.42.1.6        k3sw3   <none>           <none>
recette         database-proftpd-7c598d6698-mtp5m          1/1     Running            0          3d9h   10.42.2.3        k3sw4   <none>           <none>
recette         redis-d84785cf5-9t7sj                      1/1     Running            0          3d9h   10.42.1.7        k3sw3   <none>           <none>
kube-system     metrics-server-7566d596c8-tbfpp            1/1     Running            0          32h    10.42.1.15       k3sw3   <none>           <none>
cert-manager    cert-manager-webhook-746cf468-2t7c7        1/1     Running            0          8h     10.42.0.52       k3sh1   <none>           <none>
cert-manager    cert-manager-cainjector-5579468649-dj5fj   1/1     Running            0          8h     10.42.0.53       k3sh1   <none>           <none>
cert-manager    cert-manager-66bbb47c56-t5h6x              1/1     Running            0          8h     10.42.0.54       k3sh1   <none>           <none>
kube-system     local-path-provisioner-6d59f47c7-4vf2b     1/1     Running            0          8h     10.42.0.55       k3sh1   <none>           <none>
kube-system     coredns-8655855d6-lf2lt                    1/1     Running            0          8h     10.42.0.56       k3sh1   <none>           <none>
cattle-system   rancher-c5766f5f9-vnrht                    1/1     Running            0          8h     10.42.2.7        k3sw4   <none>           <none>
cattle-system   rancher-c5766f5f9-hqxvc                    1/1     Running            0          8h     10.42.3.6        k3sw2   <none>           <none>
recette         database-7fc89fc4bc-5xr7m                  1/1     Running            0          3d9h   10.42.2.4        k3sw4   <none>           <none>
cattle-system   rancher-c5766f5f9-n8fnm                    1/1     Running            0          8h     10.42.0.57       k3sh1   <none>           <none>
kube-system     traefik-758cd5fc85-2vdqr                   1/1     Running            0          8h     10.42.1.18       k3sw3   <none>           <none>
cattle-system   cattle-node-agent-6lrfg                    0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   359        32h    some_public_ip     k3sw4   <none>           <none>
cattle-system   cattle-node-agent-gd2mh                    0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   181        15h    some_other_public_ip   k3sw3   <none>           <none>
cattle-system   cattle-node-agent-67bqb                    0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   364        32h    some_other_public_ip     k3sh1   <none>           <none>
cattle-system   cattle-node-agent-vvfwm                    0/1     Error              361        32h    some_other_public_ip   k3sw2   <none>           <none>
cattle-system   cattle-cluster-agent-74b5586858-jnbv2      1/1     Running            100        8h     10.42.1.19       k3sw3   <none>           <none>
```

And in my rancher pod i can see they can't talk each other :

```
kubectl logs -f -n cattle-system rancher-c5766f5f9-vnrht
2020/08/19 05:18:36 [ERROR] Failed to connect to peer wss://10.42.3.6/v3/connect [local ID=10.42.2.7]: dial tcp 10.42.3.6:443: i/o timeout
2020/08/19 05:18:37 [ERROR] Failed to connect to peer wss://10.42.0.57/v3/connect [local ID=10.42.2.7]: dial tcp 10.42.0.57:443: i/o timeout
2020/08/19 05:18:51 [ERROR] Failed to connect to peer wss://10.42.3.6/v3/connect [local ID=10.42.2.7]: dial tcp 10.42.3.6:443: i/o timeout
2020/08/19 05:18:52 [ERROR] Failed to connect to peer wss://10.42.0.57/v3/connect [local ID=10.42.2.7]: dial tcp 10.42.0.57:443: i/o timeout
2020/08/19 05:19:06 [ERROR] Failed to connect to peer wss://10.42.3.6/v3/connect [local ID=10.42.2.7]: dial tcp 10.42.3.6:443: i/o timeout
2020/08/19 05:19:07 [ERROR] Failed to connect to peer wss://10.42.0.57/v3/connect [local ID=10.42.2.7]: dial tcp 10.42.0.57:443: i/o timeout
```

****Update 2 :****

I managed to fix the dial error by reseting all iptables rules, then restart k3s. I have now this error that block rancher to start:

```
E0819 06:35:44.274663       7 reflector.go:178] github.com/rancher/steve/pkg/clustercache/controller.go:164: Failed to list *summary.SummarizedObject: conversion webhook for cert-manager.io/v1alpha2, Kind=CertificateRequest failed: Post https://cert-manager-webhook.cert-manager.svc:443/convert?timeout=30s: service "cert-manager-webhook" not found                                                                   │
│ E0819 06:35:45.324406       7 reflector.go:178] github.com/rancher/steve/pkg/clustercache/controller.go:164: Failed to list *summary.SummarizedObject: conversion webhook for acme.cert-manager.io/v1alpha2, Kind=Order failed: Post https://cert-manager-webhook.cert-manager.svc:443/convert?timeout=30s: service "cert-manager-webhook" not found                                                                           │
│ E0819 06:35:49.022959       7 reflector.go:178] github.com/rancher/steve/pkg/clustercache/controller.go:164: Failed to list *summary.SummarizedObject: conversion webhook for cert-manager.io/v1alpha2, Kind=Certificate failed: Post https://cert-manager-webhook.cert-manager.svc:443/convert?timeout=30s: service "cert-manager-webhook" not found
```

Comment: Its on cloud environment or local? Did any of hardcoded ip were changed? Did you change anything lately? Any updates, upgrades, firewall changes?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. It's some bare metals servers (with public IP), no changes were made except adding an application with something like 10 PVC (and was stuck at container creating)

Comment: Sound like something messed up with your networking. Are all the pods in all the namespaces running?

Comment: @rico Yes, everything is running, and indeed it's like no one can talk each other, but i don't understand why - I updated providing list of pods and network error

Comment: Did you renew/reinstall certificates on your cluster after restart?

Comment: Yes i did renew and try different issuers. I finished reinstalling all

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalled cert-manager, and issued a self signed certificate to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as Community Wiki for better visibility.

[K3s](https://k3s.io/) is `Lightweight Kubernetes` and situation described here is very similar to `Kubeadm` behavior after [reset](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-reset/#reset-workflow).

> `kubeadm reset` is responsible for cleaning up a node local file system from files that were created using the `kubeadm init` or `kubeadm join` commands. For control-plane nodes reset also removes the local stacked etcd member of this node from the etcd cluster and also removes this node's information from the `kubeadm ClusterStatus` object. `ClusterStatus` is a `kubeadm` managed Kubernetes API object that holds a list of `kube-apiserver` endpoints.

Meaning, when you use `reset` it will delete many configurations and also `certificates`. As I mentioned in comments that issue was related with lack of certificates:

```
Failed to list *summary.SummarizedObject: conversion webhook for acme.cert-manager.io/v1alpha2, Kind=Order failed: Post https://cert-manager-webhook.cert-manager.svc:443/convert?timeout=30s: service "cert-manager-webhook" not found
```

as `reset` command removed it.

Solution was reinstall [Cert-Manager](https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/kubernetes/) and recreate [certificate](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/certificates/).